# Akka Streams: Best practice to initialise and dispose resources of a sink

Tags: akka-stream

I have a scenario where I want to write the result of a graph into a CSV. 
This includes the creation of the file, the initialisation of the file writer ([I'm using this library](https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv)) and finally, after the stream finishes, I would like to dispose/close the writer again.

Ideally, I would like to encapsulate this logic in a sink, but I'm wondering about the best practices / hooks for adding the initialization and disposal logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any type of resource, not just a file, that consumes data elements and also [needs to be closed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html):

```
type Data = ???

trait DataConsumer extends Function1[Data, Unit] with AutoCloseable
```

It is possible to create a `Sink` that will close the consumer upon completion using the [`watchTermination`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html#watchTermination[Mat2]()(matF:(Mat,scala.concurrent.Future[akka.Done])=%3EMat2):FlowOpsMat.this.ReprMat[Out,Mat2]) method of `Flow` which can be prepended:

```
def createDataConsumerSink(dataConsumer: DataConsumer) : Sink[Data,_] = 
  Flow[Data].watchTermination()( (_, f) => f foreach (_ => dataConsumer.close()))
            .to(Sink.foreach[Data](dataConsumer.apply))
```

Answer (score 2):

To write CSV content to a file using Akka Streams, use [Alpakka's CSV connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/data-transformations/csv.html) and the [`FileIO`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/FileIO$.html) utility. Here is a simple example:

```scala
val destinationPath: Path = ???

Source.single(ByteString("""header1,header2,header3
                           |1,2,3
                           |4,5,6""".stripMargin))
  .via(CsvParsing.lineScanner())
  .runWith(FileIO.toPath(destinationPath))
```

Note that `FileIO.toPath` optionally takes [`OpenOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/OpenOption.html#java.nio.file.OpenOption) settings. For example, you can stipulate the creation of the destination file if it doesn't already exist:

```scala
// ...
.runWith(
  FileIO.toPath(destinationPath, Set(StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)))
```

As for the cleaning up of the underlying resources related to the file, if you use `FileIO`, Akka Streams will take of that when the stream is completed.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks, looks perfectly for my specific use case. 
But the general question how to handle the preparation and disposing of resources is still open to me...